# PHP OOP - Connection to different host

Tags: php, oop

I got problem to connect to different host.

Please find below Connection class.

```
class Connection
{
    protected static $connectDb;
    protected $dbHost;
    protected $dbUser;
    protected $dbPass;
    protected $dbName;
    protected $charSet;

    public function __construct ($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName, $charSet){
        $this->dbHost = $dbHost;
        $this->dbUser = $dbUser;
        $this->dbPass = $dbPass;
        $this->dbName = $dbName;
        $this->charSet = $charSet;
    }

    /**
    * Connect to the database
    *
    * @return bool false on failure / mysqli MySQLi object instance on success
    */
    public function connect()
    {

        if (!isset(self::$connectDb)) {
                self::$connectDb = new mysqli($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass, $this->dbName);
        }

        if (self::$connectDb->connect_errno) {
          printf("Connection failed: %s\n", self::$connectDb->connect_error);
          exit();
        }

        if ($this->charSet) {
            if (!self::$connectDb->set_charset($this->charSet)) {
                printf("Error loading character set ".$this->charSet.": %s\n", self::$connectDb->error);
                exit();
            } else {
                // printf("Current character set: %s\n", self::$connectDb->character_set_name());
            } 
        }

        return self::$connectDb;
    }

    /**
    * Query the database
    *
    * @param $query The query string
    * @return mixed The result of the mysqli::query() function
    */
    public function query($query)
    {
        $conn = $this->connect();

        $result = $conn->query($query);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

I create connection like below:-

```
$conn1 = new Connection('localhost', '[user1]', '[password1]', '[db_name1]', 'utf8');

$conn2 = new Connection('xxx.xxx.xx.xx', '[user2]', '[password2]', '[db_name2]', 'utf8');
```

But when I run query on $conn2, it still connect and run on $conn1.

Sample query:-

```
$result = $conn1->query([select_query_from_db_name1]);

foreach($result as $value) {
    $conn2->query([insert_into_db_name2]);
}
```

Hope anyone can point me where the problem as i also still learning on oop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `self::$connectDb` is static and already set.

Comment: You are using a static property which is THE SAME for all instances of the class. Both connections will have exactly the same $connectDb so they will always use the same connection

Comment: Hi. Thanks both of you. Now I manage to connect to another host after I remove static property. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, the [`static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) keyword means that a variable will, in that case, stay the same for all instances of a class, so removing it will allow for two different `Connection` instances to have two different connections.

However, that is a really unintuitive use case for static, as static properties are more like class constants. For instance, you could define the tax rate of a calculator class as a static private property, and use it with `self::TAX_RATE` everywhere, without the "cost" of a property.

---

If I may however, I believe you could further improve your code by just dropping this connection class. It really has nothing better than the basic `\mysqli` object, and in fact will be troublesome to maintain.

The `query()` fuction implemented here is terrible: it prevents the use of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), leaving you wide open to sql injection.

The manual error checking that is implemented is also useless, setting error reporting at application level will already allow the connection to tell you if it can't connect, with much better details than rewriting everything.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this direct into the constructor,

```
self::$connectDb = new mysqli($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser,
 $this->dbPass, $this->dbName);
```

You can also use this into constructor,

```
if (!isset(self::$connectDb)) {             
   self::$connectDb = new mysqli($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass, $this->dbName);
        }
```

but in this case should use a parameter $newConn = true, in the

```
$conn1 = new Connection('localhost', '[user1]', '[password1]', '[db_name1]', 'utf8', $newConn);
```

Now you constructor signature should be

```
public function __construct ($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName, $charSet, $newCon = false){
        $this->dbHost = $dbHost;
        $this->dbUser = $dbUser;
        $this->dbPass = $dbPass;
        $this->dbName = $dbName;
        $this->charSet = $charSet;

 if (!isset(self::$connectDb) || $newConn) {
                 self::$connectDb = new mysqli($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass, $this->dbName);
         }


    }
```

Comment: why should they do that? how is that better (it's not). also, you missed the real problem: the static keyword...

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier , thanks for notice, Actually when i was reading the quetsion the "protected static $connectDb;" was hide as i scroll the mouse.